# Using twig translations inside Moustache inside Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, mustache, verbatim

I have a moustache template inside my twig template. I use the moustache template in javascript and it contains some text and JS variables.

```
{# _partial.html.twig #}
{% verbatim %}
    <script id="insuranceOptionTpl" type="text/template">
        {{ #. }}
            <strong>My template is {{ adjective }}</strong>
        {{ /. }}
    </script>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Now I need to internationalize this page but my twig translations won't work inside verbatim. Is there any elegant ways to do that? I will probably have many different texts to translate, so ending and starting a new verbatim block all the time is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the verbatim block and by customizing Twig delimiters to be differents than Mustache ones, replacing `{{` and `}}` by `[[` and `]]` for example (as explained [in Twig doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax)), you'll be able to use Twig and Mustache in the same template:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment'   => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block'     => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable'  => array('[[', ']]'),
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```

As most of your templates are already in Twig, you can change Mustache delimiters instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var output = $("#output");    
    var template = $("#insuranceOptionTpl").html();

    //Custom tags for Mustache
    var customTags = [ '[[', ']]' ];
    Mustache.tags = customTags;

    // render string
    var data1 = "Hello world!";
    var html = Mustache.render(template, data1);
    output.append(html);
});
```

Comment: Oh, of course! I was thinking of using JS translations but this is really not elegant. I have way too many twig templates and just a few mustache ones. Can I change just Mustache's delimiters?